# Erro: nao pode ser chamada na lista de argumentos c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Estive tentando  usar o bunifu transition no windows form c++, porem sem secesso por causa do erro. No c# ficaria "bunifutransition.showsync(painel);" mas no c++ nem um conversor de c# pra c++ resolve.

C#

```
Private: System::Void bunifuImenu_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e){
     bunifutransition.HideSync(panel3);
     bunifutransition.ShowSync(panel4);
}
```

C++ ERRO

```
Private: System::Void bunifuImenu_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e){
     bunifutransition->HideSync(panel3);
     bunifutransition->ShowSync(panel4);
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código referente à pergunta como texto e não como imagem. Depois aproveite e formate-o com o botão `{}` do editor na pergunta ou através do atalho `Ctrl + k`.

Comment: tem como me dar um exemplo pq nao ficou muito claro

Comment: Amigo, é só copiar o código que você tem no visual studio e colar aqui. Depois precisa apenas de aplicar a formatação no editor da pergunta.

Comment: @Isac ta ai o exemplo, desculpe a incompreensão pensei que estivesse falando do codigo